# Proving $SU(n)$ is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to prove $SU(n)$ is a manifold through the followin method:

> Defone $\phi: GL(n;\mathbb C)\rightarrow Herm(n) \times\mathbb R $ by $\phi(A)=(AA^*-id, i(det(A)-det(A^*))$, then $(0,0)$ is a regular value.
>    ($Herm(n)$ is the set of $n\times n$ Hermitian(self-adjoint) matrix.)

My question is, how to check $(0,0)$ is a regular value? I don't know how to write down its differential map, let alone checking its surjectivity at points $\phi^{-1}(0,0)$.

Comment: Simiilar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465284/prove-that-un-is-a-manifold)

Answer (score 1):

A hint, which I have not carried out completely, but I think will get you where you want to go:

You might consider $2n^2$ independent paths in $GL(n;C)$ --- I'd recommend 
$$
\gamma_{ij}(t) = I + t E_{ij}
$$
where $E_{ij}$ is all zeroes except for the $(i,j)$-entry, for the first $n^2$ paths, and 
$$
\eta_{ij}(t) = I + t \mathbf i  E_{ij}
$$
for the other $n^2$. The images of these under $\phi$ are $2n^2$ paths in $Herm(n)$, and you can compute the derivative of each at $t = 0$ pretty easily. The resulting $2n^2$ matrices span the image of the differential $d\phi$. It should (I hope) be obvious that many of them are linearly independent, enough to show that $(0,0)$ is a regular value.

It might be a little easier to chose something like 
$$
\gamma^1_{ij}(t) = I + t E_{ij} - t E_{ij}  \\
\gamma^2_{ij}(t) = I + t E_{ij} + t E_{ij}
$$
because the algebra works out more nicely, but this is totally a guess.

It also might make sense to choose a first bunch of paths that are tangent to $SU(n)$, e.g., ones that look like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin t & -\cos t\\
\cos t & \sin t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
, but with these put into the $ii, ij, ji$ and $jj$ entry of the matrix; the tangent vector for such a path will end up being zero. (You'll want to find exactly $dim(SU(n))$ such paths!)

Then choose a second batch that are obviously "linearly independent" (or better still, "orthogonal") to these, perhaps inserting something like 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin t & \cos t\\
\cos t & \sin t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
into various blocks (once again, choosing enough to fill out the complementary dimension). Then it'll be obvious what the rank looks like. The second class of paths will have tangents (at $t = 0$) that constitute a set of independent matrices that's large enough to show that the rank of $D\phi$ is nonzero.

By the way, I'd strongly recommend doing this for $n = 3$, say, after which the general case may become transparent.

Comment: But there is an $\mathbb R$ part in the image of $d\phi$, I am not sure those two parts in the image will match if I only consider the left part.

Comment: You'll surely need to think of at least one path in the domain that is non-constant in the second part; something like a square matrix with entries $1, it, 1,  1$ will give you $det A - det A* = (1+it) - (1-it) = 2t $. The derivative of that is 2. :)

Comment: But if a specific left part is obtained, the right part will be another specific value, I need to make sure all images for example $(a,b_1), (a,b_2), (a, b_3)...$ do lie in its image.

Comment: No. You need to show the derivative has maximal rank. And that's what I've told you how to do. Tell you what: try doing the $2 \times 2$ case -- should be even easier -- in the way I recommended, and get yourself 8 different pairs in $M_{33} \times \mathbb R$ representing tangents to various paths, and add that work to your question, and we can go from there.