# Proving that $U(n)$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In order to prove that  $U(n, \mathbb C) := \{A \in M_n(\mathbb C): A^*A = I\}$ is a smooth manifold we can define a function $ F : M_n(\mathbb C) \to H_n(\mathbb C)$ where $F(A)=A^{\dagger}A$ and prove that it is the preimage of a regular value, the identity. In order to be a regular value we must prove that the differential of this function is surjective.

I've already seen this post: [Prove that $U(n)$ is a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465284/prove-that-un-is-a-manifold) but how do we prove that the differential of this function is surjective.

EDIT:

When I try to compute the differential, given the definition:

$$ F(A+V) = F(A)+d_AF+Q_A(V)$$

ignoring the quadratic term, and plugging in the definition of our function $F$ I arrive at:

$$ d_AF(V)=F(A+V)-F(V)$$
$$ d_AF(V)= (A+V)^{\dagger}(A+V)-V^{\dagger}V$$
$$ d_AF(V)= (A)^{\dagger}A + (A)^{\dagger}V + (V)^{\dagger}A$$

what happens to the first term, in order for the differential to be the same as the one stated in the post?

Comment: In the link you provided, the accepted answer shows that the differential is surjective by constructing a solution to the equation $\mathrm{d}_AF (X) = B$.

Comment: I just dont understand why that justifies the surjectivity of the differential of $F$

Comment: Well, write down carefully the definition of surjectivity

Comment: You want to prove the differential has maximal rank. It suffices to find its kernel.

Comment: But why is the differential of $F$  given by the expression in that post?

Comment: Try to compute the differential by fixing $A$ and $H$ and looking to $F(A+H)$: you should find $F(A) + L_A(H) + Q_A(H)$ where $L_A$ is linear and $Q_A$ is quadratic with respect to $H$. It follows that $L_A = \mathrm{d}_AF$ if you know the definition of a differential. If you don't understand this, just go back to basic exercices about differential of a function.

Comment: I edited the question, I dont understand why it doesn't give the same result

Comment: $F(A+H) = (A+H)^*(A+H) = A^*A + A^* H + H^*A + H^*H = F(A) + \left(A^*H + H^*A \right) + (H^*H)$. This is just basic symbolic calculus.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for being so annoying